# How do I host a static website on S3 with an ACL?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I'm currently hosting a project of mine on S3 and that results in a URL like: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-project/index.html

Using Cloudfront, I'm able to make this a lot nicer so that I can access this page using https://my-project.com/. I can add an ACL to this url so that only certain IPs can access it, but the bucket itself will still be wide open to the world. How would I also apply the ACL to the bucket?

Comment: If you are using CF with ACL, do you still need to allow direct access to the underlying bucket? you can turn off bucket access in the CF distribution setting - might be a lot easier that way and tbh, I don't think you can do Geo-like ACL on the bucket itself.

Comment: "you can turn off bucket access in the CF distribution setting"

That sounds like exactly the thing I want. I've gotta try that!